# Can't find solution to resolve this error MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I apologize in advance that I will not be able to provide a code example.

All what I can show is the traceback error that I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mydbapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 983, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/home/mydbapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 682, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

I've read a lot of SO questions about this error but without being able to reproduce any solution unfortunately.

Where do you think that the problem could come from ?

Is it possible that it's related to a problem of SQLAlchemy or MySQLdb version ? (mysqlclient==2.1.0, PyMySQL==1.0.2, SQLAlchemy==1.4.35)

Also I would like to know if there is a way to debug more precisely where the error happen in the code and which command exactly is "out of sync" ?

Thanks

Comment: "Is it possible that it's related to a problem of SQLAlchemy or MySQLdb version ?" - It's *possible*, so consider an [edit] to your question to tell us what those versions are.

Comment: If you can't show us the code it's not possible to offer much help. But typically this error message on a rollback indicates there is  no transaction to roll back. This is either because your connection is set to do implicit commit, or because the `begin transaction` was not issued, or it was issued but failed, and your code did not trap that.

Comment: @BoarGules What do you mean by "your connection is set to do implicit commit" ?

Comment: @Rivaille https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks. What form does it take in SQLAlchemy

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#session-level-vs-engine-level-transaction-control